# Postgres index on lpad function

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, database-indexes

I have a select query that has the below where clause.

```
where lpad(a.x,10,'0') = lpad(b.y,10,'0')
```

This doesn't use the indices I have on x and y. So I created the below indexes too.

```
create index x_idx ON table_a USING btree(lpad(x, 10, '0'));
create index y_idx ON table_b USING btree(lpad(y, 10, '0'));
```

Still, the above query doesn't use the indexes.

What am I missing here? Is it not possible to create indices on functions like `lpad`?

**Update 1: Here is a complete sample.**

Please note that I had to make this sample a bit complex to match my real case as it seemed the simple case worked fine.

```
CREATE TABLE sellers (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    city_id VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE buyers (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    city_id VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sellers_2 (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    city_id VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE buyers_2 (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    city_id VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL
);
```

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
select *
from 
    (select s.city_id as s_c, b.city_id as b_c, * from sellers s 
    join buyers b on lpad(s.city_id, 10, '0') = lpad(b.city_id, 10, '0')) one
join
    (select s2.city_id as s2_c, b2.city_id as b2_c, * from sellers_2 s2 inner 
    join buyers_2 b2 on lpad(s2.city_id, 10, '0') = lpad(b2.city_id, 10, '0')) two
on lpad(one.s_c, 10, '0') = lpad(two.s2_c, 10, '0');
```

Create indices:

```
create index seller_city_idx on sellers USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index buyer_city_idx on buyers USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index seller2_city_idx on sellers_2 USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index buyer2_city_idx on buyers_2 USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
```

After indices:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Hash Join  (cost=3.41..4.76 rows=6 width=4616) (actual time=0.120..0.129 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                            |
  Output: s.city_id, b.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, s.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, b.city_id, s2.city_id, b2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, s2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username, b2.city_id|
  Hash Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                     |
  Buffers: shared hit=4                                                                                                                                                                             |
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.27..3.53 rows=6 width=1914) (actual time=0.044..0.050 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                      |
        Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username                                                                             |
        Hash Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                               |
        Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                                                                                       |
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.14..2.29 rows=6 width=1276) (actual time=0.025..0.029 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                |
              Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username                                                                                                            |
              Hash Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                          |
              Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                                 |
              ->  Seq Scan on public.sellers s  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                        |
                    Output: s.user_id, s.username, s.city_id                                                                                                                                        |
                    Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                           |
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                |
                    Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username                                                                                                                                        |
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                    |
                    Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                           |
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.buyers b  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                   |
                          Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username                                                                                                                                  |
                          Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                     |
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                      |
              Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username                                                                                                                                           |
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                          |
              Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                                 |
              ->  Seq Scan on public.sellers_2 s2  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                     |
                    Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username                                                                                                                                     |
                    Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                           |
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                                                            |
        Output: b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username                                                                                                                                                 |
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                                |
        Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                                       |
        ->  Seq Scan on public.buyers_2 b2  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=638) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=6 loops=1)                                                                            |
              Output: b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username                                                                                                                                           |
              Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                                 |
Planning time: 1.665 ms                                                                                                                                                                             |
Execution time: 0.199 ms                                                                                                                                                                            |
```

My question is about `one JOIN two`.

**Update 2: with 100k data**

Before indices:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Merge Join  (cost=39743.28..250002416743.28 rows=12500000000000 width=88) (actual time=1501.115..1710.061 rows=6545 loops=1)                                                                        |
  Output: s.city_id, b.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, s.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, b.city_id, s2.city_id, b2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, s2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username, b2.city_id|
  Merge Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                    |
  Buffers: shared hit=2529, temp read=3282 written=3128                                                                                                                                             |
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=19871.64..1020871.64 rows=50000000 width=32) (actual time=752.228..838.543 rows=40014 loops=1)                                                                              |
        Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username                                                                                                                  |
        Merge Cond: ((lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)) = (lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)))                                                                                           |
        Buffers: shared hit=1267, temp read=1630 written=1564                                                                                                                                       |
        ->  Sort  (cost=9935.82..10185.82 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=360.257..383.275 rows=100000 loops=1)                                                                                  |
              Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                    |
              Sort Key: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                                                    |
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3904kB                                                                                                                                             |
              Buffers: shared hit=636, temp read=488 written=489                                                                                                                                    |
              ->  Seq Scan on public.sellers s  (cost=0.00..1631.00 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.019..20.382 rows=100000 loops=1)                                                           |
                    Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)                                                                                                |
                    Buffers: shared hit=631                                                                                                                                                         |
        ->  Sort  (cost=9935.82..10185.82 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=391.962..403.480 rows=106929 loops=1)                                                                                  |
              Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, (lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                    |
              Sort Key: (lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                                                    |
              Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 4296kB                                                                                                                                              |
              Buffers: shared hit=631, temp read=1108 written=1075                                                                                                                                  |
              ->  Seq Scan on public.buyers b  (cost=0.00..1631.00 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.029..20.583 rows=100000 loops=1)                                                            |
                    Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)                                                                                                |
                    Buffers: shared hit=631                                                                                                                                                         |
  ->  Materialize  (cost=19871.64..1145871.64 rows=50000000 width=32) (actual time=748.780..841.877 rows=42013 loops=1)                                                                             |
        Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username                                                                                                            |
        Buffers: shared hit=1262, temp read=1652 written=1564                                                                                                                                       |
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=19871.64..1020871.64 rows=50000000 width=32) (actual time=748.769..835.644 rows=39909 loops=1)                                                                        |
              Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username                                                                                                      |
              Merge Cond: ((lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)) = (lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)))                                                                                   |
              Buffers: shared hit=1262, temp read=1652 written=1564                                                                                                                                 |
              ->  Sort  (cost=9935.82..10185.82 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=356.547..379.828 rows=99998 loops=1)                                                                             |
                    Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, (lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                          |
                    Sort Key: (lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                                             |
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3904kB                                                                                                                                       |
                    Buffers: shared hit=631, temp read=488 written=489                                                                                                                              |
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.sellers_2 s2  (cost=0.00..1631.00 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.026..20.087 rows=100000 loops=1)                                                  |
                          Output: s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)                                                                                      |
                          Buffers: shared hit=631                                                                                                                                                   |
              ->  Sort  (cost=9935.82..10185.82 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=392.207..403.950 rows=107019 loops=1)                                                                            |
                    Output: b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username, (lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                          |
                    Sort Key: (lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                                             |
                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 4296kB                                                                                                                                        |
                    Buffers: shared hit=631, temp read=1119 written=1075                                                                                                                            |
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.buyers_2 b2  (cost=0.00..1631.00 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.032..20.954 rows=100000 loops=1)                                                   |
                          Output: b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username, lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text)                                                                                      |
                          Buffers: shared hit=631                                                                                                                                                   |
Planning time: 0.729 ms                                                                                                                                                                             |
Execution time: 1719.682 ms                                                                                                                                                                         |                                                                                           |
```

Create indices:

```
create index seller_city_idx on sellers USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index buyer_city_idx on buyers USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index seller2_city_idx on sellers_2 USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
create index buyer2_city_idx on buyers_2 USING btree (lpad(city_id, 10, '0'));
```

After indices:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Merge Join  (cost=1.67..36697.70 rows=238630 width=88) (actual time=0.417..432.964 rows=6545 loops=1)                                                                                               |
  Output: s.city_id, b.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, s.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, b.city_id, s2.city_id, b2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username, s2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username, b2.city_id|
  Merge Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                                     |
  Buffers: shared hit=401391                                                                                                                                                                        |
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.83..15503.24 rows=133622 width=32) (actual time=0.060..196.892 rows=39973 loops=1)                                                                                        |
        Output: s.city_id, s.user_id, s.username, b2.city_id, b2.user_id, b2.username                                                                                                               |
        Merge Cond: (lpad((s.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((b2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                              |
        Buffers: shared hit=200678                                                                                                                                                                  |
        ->  Index Scan using seller_city_idx on public.sellers s  (cost=0.42..6088.39 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.003..47.076 rows=100000 loops=1)                                         |
              Output: s.user_id, s.username, s.city_id                                                                                                                                              |
              Buffers: shared hit=100347                                                                                                                                                            |
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..6242.40 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.010..60.183 rows=107144 loops=1)                                                                                  |
              Output: b2.user_id, b2.username, b2.city_id                                                                                                                                           |
              Buffers: shared hit=100331                                                                                                                                                            |
              ->  Index Scan using buyer2_city_idx on public.buyers_2 b2  (cost=0.42..5992.40 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.005..47.293 rows=99999 loops=1)                                  |
                    Output: b2.user_id, b2.username, b2.city_id                                                                                                                                     |
                    Buffers: shared hit=100331                                                                                                                                                      |
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.83..15894.00 rows=134467 width=32) (actual time=0.041..203.895 rows=42294 loops=1)                                                                                       |
        Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username                                                                                                               |
        Buffers: shared hit=200713                                                                                                                                                                  |
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.83..15557.83 rows=134467 width=32) (actual time=0.039..197.896 rows=40144 loops=1)                                                                                  |
              Output: b.city_id, b.user_id, b.username, s2.city_id, s2.user_id, s2.username                                                                                                         |
              Merge Cond: (lpad((s2.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text) = lpad((b.city_id)::text, 10, '0'::text))                                                                                        |
              Buffers: shared hit=200713                                                                                                                                                            |
              ->  Index Scan using seller2_city_idx on public.sellers_2 s2  (cost=0.42..6092.34 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.005..46.555 rows=100000 loops=1)                               |
                    Output: s2.user_id, s2.username, s2.city_id                                                                                                                                     |
                    Buffers: shared hit=100360                                                                                                                                                      |
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..6346.41 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.007..60.809 rows=107087 loops=1)                                                                            |
                    Output: b.user_id, b.username, b.city_id                                                                                                                                        |
                    Buffers: shared hit=100353                                                                                                                                                      |
                    ->  Index Scan using buyer_city_idx on public.buyers b  (cost=0.42..6096.41 rows=100000 width=16) (actual time=0.005..47.890 rows=100000 loops=1)                               |
                          Output: b.user_id, b.username, b.city_id                                                                                                                                  |
                          Buffers: shared hit=100353                                                                                                                                                |
Planning time: 4.604 ms                                                                                                                                                                             |
Execution time: 433.255 ms                                                                                                                                                                          |
```

Now it looks like the indices have been used.

I'm still learning to read the `explain` output. So I have a question, have the indices been used for the `one join two on lpad(one.s_c, 10, '0') = lpad(two.s2_c, 10, '0')` operation?

Comment: Could you please share the results (in plain text in this topic) for EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your SELECT statement? And please share the complete SQL, your current WHERE condition isn't valid using a double WHERE.

Comment: My mistake. I fixed the double `where`. I will post the other details.

Comment: Updated the question with a sample and my observations. Thanks.

Comment: Uhh, there is not much I can do: Execution time: 0.199 ms. This is because the tables are almost empty. This is also why the database doesn't use an index, that would be slower. Add at least a couple of thousand records and try again. Your could force the database to use an index, but that doesn't really help: SET enable_seqscan TO OFF;

Comment: When a whole table fits in a single disk block the engine can get it right away in 1 read... so that's what PostgreSQL is doing (a `Seq Scan`). If the table had 10k rows it would probably realize using the index is a better solution.

Comment: Got it. Please have a look at the update 2.

Comment: It can use those indexes, it just thinks something else will be faster.  It you disable merge joins and hash joins,  it might decide to one of those indexes.